# How to use ListIndex to find row of Combobox value?

Tags: excel, vba, combobox

I'm trying to set a "Make Changes" button for my userform that changes the appropriate record in the spreadsheet according to any changes made in the userform.

The userform populates according to the selection made on "BusCombo".

I'm trying to set n to the row of the "BusCombo" selection. I found a suggestion to use ListIndex. I can't find information on how ListIndex works.

```
Private Sub MkChgButton_Click()

Dim sh As Worksheet
Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Customers")

Dim n
With Me.BusCombo
    n = .ListIndex
End With

''''''submit changes

sh.Range("A" & n).Value = Me.BusCombo.Value
sh.Range("B" & n).Value = Me.ServFreqCombo.Value
sh.Range("K" & n).Value = Me.TimeText.Value
sh.Range("C" & n).Value = Me.RateText.Value
sh.Range("D" & n).Value = Me.PayFormCombo.Value
sh.Range("E" & n).Value = Me.PayFreqCombo.Value
sh.Range("F" & n).Value = Me.DayText.Value
sh.Range("G" & n).Value = Me.StartText.Value
sh.Range("H" & n).Value = Me.PayDateText.Value
sh.Range("I" & n).Value = Me.EmpCombo.Value

End Sub
```

Comment: Items in a ComboBox drop-down list are numbers from 1 up. The first item will have the `ListIndex` 1, the second one 2, etc. I presume that you want a sheet row which is different. Consider using an invisible TextBox or Label where you record the sheet row when all its data are loaded. The more demanding solution would add a second column to the ComboBox where you can store the row number (also invisibly, unless you want it displayed). Use the `ListIndex` property to access hidden columns and items in the list, like a 2-D array or, in fact, spreadsheet cells where `ListIndex` is the row #.

Comment: `ListIndex` is actually `0` based.

Comment: Would there be a better method that comes to mind I could look into besides ListIndex?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a little demo that shows you how to search through the `List` items in the Combobox:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
  ' add items to the combobox
  With ComboBox1
    .AddItem ("stuff1")
    .List(0, 1) = "test1"
    .AddItem ("stuff2")
    .List(1, 1) = "test2"
    .AddItem ("stuff3")
    .List(2, 1) = "test3"
  End With
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
  Dim i As Integer
  Dim SearchString As String
  
  SearchString = "test3"
  
  ' loop through all the items, looking in the 2nd column (column index=1)
  For i = 0 To ComboBox1.ListCount - 1
    If ComboBox1.List(i, 1) = SearchString Then
      MsgBox ("Found it at row index " & i)
      Exit Sub
    End If
  Next
  MsgBox SearchString & " not found"
  
End Sub
```